# Convert Hidden Field into PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need some help. I have this hidden field in my html code and I am adding a value to in javascript as an array. In my php code I want to get the value of the hidden field and treat it as a php array. However that is not working for me. Instead it's treating the whole value as one. How can I convert the hidden field as value into an php array, and print out a value at a specific index.

Here is the code for my hidden field

```
<form name = "wall" action="Respon.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name ="widths[]" id ="widths" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name ="lengths[]" id ="lengths" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

This is the javascript code where I am adding a value to the hidden field

```
widthL.push(Number(widths));
lengthL.push(Number(lengths));

$("#widths").val(widthL);
$("#lengths").val(lengthL);
```

As you can see I am converting those value into a number, since I am getting my value from input text field.

And this is the php code for getting the hidden field value.

```
<?php

$index = 0;

$widthlist = array();
$lengthlist = array();

$widths = $_REQUEST['widths'];
$lengths = $_REQUEST['lengths'];

array_push($widthlist, $widths);
array_push($lengthlist, $lengths);

$count = count($widthlist);

foreach ($widthlist as $w => $value) {
   echo $widthlist[$index];
   echo "<br />";
}

for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {

   echo $widthlist[$x];
   echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I try both of the above two method and nothing is working. Its printing all of them on the same line as one value

Can someone please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in this way. I think you should serialize these objects and after that in the server unserialize them.

```
widthL.push(Number(widths));
lengthL.push(Number(lengths));

// 
var serializedwidthL = JSON.stringify(widthL);
var serializedlengthL = JSON.stringify(lengthL);
//
$("#widths").val(serializedlengthL );
$("#lengths").val(serializedlengthL );
```

And then when you retrieve your array in the server :

```
$widthlist = json_decode($_REQUEST['widths'], true);
$lengthlist = json_decode($_REQUEST['widths'], true);
```

That will give you an array with separated elements.

Comment: Thank for the help. I did it like you told me and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to use ajax here to access javascript variables through php. In your code, after pushing the values use ajax with the required values as the data and script location as the same file.
You have to send both array through a json object in data field.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: { arr2 : a2 },
    success: function() {
        alert1('ok, sent');
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case I wouldn't be able to access the value when I refresh the page. Because after when I get all the data I have to click the submit button that will take me to the next page where I will able to see my result. If I use Ajax I wouldn't be able to access those value as client. Which I would to access. That why I am saving it to an hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
widthL.push(Number(widths));
lengthL.push(Number(lengths));
...

var tags = [];
var i;
for(i=0; i<widthL.length; i++) {
    tags.push('<input type="hidden" name="widths[]" value="'+widthL[i]+'" />');
}
for(i=0; i<lengthL.length; i++) {
    tags.push('<input type="hidden" name="lengths[]" value="'+lengthL[i]+'" />');
}
$("fieldset").html(tags.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is as @aimadnet suggested, to add one field for each value. The reason for that is that in order for PHP to parse the field as an array, you must post the field *once for each value*, all named equal, ended with `[]`.

My suggestion is an alternative with less code. If you're sure about the values (either you're generating them or you validate the user's input), you could send them as string, with only one hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name ="widths" id ="widths" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name ="lengths" id ="lengths" value="" />

$("#widths").val(widthL.join("|")); //or any other separator
$("#lengths").val(lengthL.join("|"));

$widths = explode('|',$_REQUEST['widths']);
$lengths = explode('|',$_REQUEST['lengths']);
//TODO validate as numbers. You should validate them with any other method anyways
```